How can I align my X axis label with my y axis?
I am trying to align my x axis label with my y axis. As you can see in the picture, I want to align CD103 and CD69 with the frequency numbers (0.00). However it's not working. Here is my code.
recolonization_phenotype_graph <- final_recolonization_phenotype_data %>% 
  filter(Tcell_subset== "CD4^'+'" & !Residency_markers=="+\n-\n") %>%
  filter(!phenotype=="CD29" & !phenotype=="CD18") %>% 
  filter (!X== "Specimen_001_Colon-digest_mouse_001.fcs") %>% 
  filter (!X== "Specimen_001_Colon-digest_mouse_004.fcs") %>% 
  filter (!X== "Specimen_001_Colon-digest_mouse_005.fcs") %>% 
  filter (!X== "Specimen_001_Colon-digest_mouse_009.fcs") %>%
  filter (!X=="Specimen_001_Colon-wash_mouse_004.fcs" & !X=="Specimen_001_Colon-wash_mouse_012.fcs" & !X=="Specimen_001_Colon-wash_mouse_001.fcs"& !X=="Specimen_001_Colon-wash_mouse_007.fcs") %>%
  ggplot(final_recolonization_phenotype_data, mapping = aes(x= Residency_markers, y= Frequency, colour = group), width = 10, height = 5, unit = "in") + 
  facet_grid(state~phenotype, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(size = 0.1, position = position_jitterdodge()) + theme_minimal() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5, axis.title.y = element_text(element_text(size = 6, face = "bold")), axis.title.x = element_text(size = 6, face = "bold", hjust = 0, vjust = 18), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, face = "bold"), strip.text = element_text( size = 6, face = "bold"), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6, face = "bold")) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + 
  labs (x = "CD103\nCD69\n") +  
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  scale_colour_manual ( values = c("#ff007f","#af6df9","#00008B"), labels = ggplot2:::parse_safe) + 
  labs(color = "Group")


I tried different functions including: annotate().

Can you say more about (or show) what you mean by "align CD103 and CD69 with the frequency numbers"? I suspect it will be easier to use annotate("text", .....) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,NA), clip = "off") to place text in "coordinate space" beyond the plot limits than by adjusting the axis title spacing.

Can you see the CD103 and CD69 written on the x axis? This is my X axis label. I would like to shift it to the left a little bit so that it aligns with the 0.00 on the y axis

I've tried what @JonSpring suggested. However it's not exactly working. I get 12 new CD103 CD69 labels appearing

Please make your question reproducible by including some data (doesn't need to be real, ideally <50 rows) that is representative enough to demonstrate your issue. It's often most helpful to run dput(SOME_DATA)  to create a "code recipe" that you can paste into the body of your question so that others can run it to reproduce that data.

Here's a simpler version of your chart. (It doesn't appear that the detail or theming besides the x axis title and the facets are particularly relevant to the crux of the question. Without including example data, there's not much we can do with the question code.)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(floor(wt)), mpg-10)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~gear) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 6, face = "bold", hjust = 0, vjust = 18)) +
  labs (x = "CD103\nCD69\n")
  


Here, I put the text instead as a geom with a single row of data, placed outside the plot area. I add spaces in the text to keep it aligned but closer to the axis labels instead of right against the plot edge.
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(floor(wt)), mpg-10)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~gear) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.4, y = -2.5, label = "CD103  \nCD69  "),
            hjust = 1,
            data = data.frame(gear = 3)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, NA), clip = "off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.5), "line"))


We could alternatively use hjust = 1.2 or other values >1, but a downside of that approach is that the alignment would vary for lines of text of different length.

Thanks @Jon ! What is the 'data = data.frame(gear = 3)' function? How can I change it for my data?

That was to make the text appear only once, next to the first facet, which in my example is the gear = 3 one. In your data, you may need to specify something like data.frame(state = "wash", phenotype = "CD44") to specify which facet the text attaches to.

Thanks, for some reason I now get an error message: Error: in geom_text() ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'group' not found
Backtrace:

base (local) <fn>(x)
ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
base::lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)


Your global aes() says that each layer should vary in color based on a variable in that layer's data called group. We don't want that for this added layer. I'd suggest moving aes(colour = group) out of the global level (where it is applied to all geoms) and into the boxplot and jittered point layers. Either that, or add inherit.aes = FALSE) into the text layer.

Thanks @Jon ! I tried both your suggestions. The second one works, but then it's still the same problem, the CD103 and CD69 remains in the same place

I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by "remains in the same place."

Sorry for the confusion, what I mean is that it's still not aligned. The same way from my initial image (see initial image from my question)
